# Optimizing bitset operation

Tags: c++, bitset

I am looking to optimize this piece of code. `BitSetPattern` is of size 512 while `BitSetOut` is 2048 bits long.

Basically what this code does, it takes 4 BitSetPatterns and creates a BitSetOut by concatinating them. Copying by one bit takes too much time.

I figured an OR along with a SHIFT would solve the case, but the operators only take bitsets of the same length. There is also no way to initialize a bitset with a smaller one and fill the remaining bits with zeroes.

```
unsigned outputIter = 0;
BitSetPattern output(0);

for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
{
    BitSetOut currentInput = this->input[ i ]->getOutput();
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < currentInput.size(); j++)
    {
        output[ outputIter ] = currentInput[ j ];
        outputIter++;
    }
}
return output;
```

I have already profiled the code, and this is the method that takes too much time.

Comment: What exactly are the underlying types of these bit sets? Are they `std::bitset`?

Comment: (1) What is `BitSetOut` type? If it's some type of structure instead of a reference, the assignment may require too much work on copying data. (2) What is `BitSetout::size()` implementation? If it is not an just inlined fetching of a counter, it may be too expensive to call it every iteration. Try `for (unsigned j = 0, s = currentInput.size(); j < s; j++)` instead.

Comment: @CiaPan As yzt said, they are of type std::bitset. ::size() returns a compile-time constant, so I think this gets inlined by the compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very ***UNSAFE*** solution that you should ***NOT*** use:

```
assert (sizeof(output) == output.size() / 8);
assert ((output.size() / 8) == 0);

int offset = 0;
for (int i = 3; i >= 0; --i)
{
    auto const sz = input[i].size();

    assert ((sz % 8) == 0);
    assert (offset + (sz / 8) <= output.size());

    memcpy (((char*)&(output)) + offset, (char*)&(input[i]), sz / 8);
    offset += sz / 8;
}
```

Basically, this tries to be safe and make sure there is nothing else inside a bitset except for the bits (no padding, alignments, maybe size or even compressed bits.) And then copies them as a whole.

There is nothing in the standard (AFAIK) that guarantees that this will work. It may not even work for existing implementations, but I believe that it "*should*" work for a straightforward `std::bitset` implementation.

It *might* be possible to speed up the copy part even more. Since you know the size of your data, and it is very small, you can directly write SSE or even AVX intrinsics that will copy those 512 bits for the source address to the destination address.

Here are three more things to try:

1. If you are absolutely sure that your sizes remain constant (at e.g. 2048 and 512 bits,) use the constant values and drop the arithmetic and assertions. This *might* help depending on how your compiler treats `memcpy` (some compilers optimize the hell out of it under certain circumstances, e.g. if the sizes are constant and a multiple of word size, etc.)
2. Make sure your bit buffers are allocated at addresses that are multiples of cache line size (e.g. 64 bytes.) This is to make sure you don't touch more cache lines than necessary.)
3. You can try and help the memory "prefetcher" by touching the *next* input buffer on each iteration. For example:

   ```
   char * output_ptr = (char *)&output;
   char * input_ptrs [4] = {(char*)&(input[0]), (char*)&(input[1]), ...};
   volatile char dummy = 0;

   dummy += input_ptrs[2][0];                    // prefetch the next one
   memcpy (output_ptr +   0, input_ptrs[3], 64); // copy

   dummy += input_ptrs[1][0];                    // prefetch the next one
   memcpy (output_ptr +  64, input_ptrs[2], 64); // copy

   dummy += input_ptrs[0][0];                    // prefetch the next one
   memcpy (output_ptr + 128, input_ptrs[1], 64); // copy

   memcpy (output_ptr + 192, input_ptrs[0], 64); // copy
   ```

Comment: could you elaborate on the SSE and AVX?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: Basically, I mean that since you are copying 64 bytes at a time, you can use 4 (possibly) pipelined loads into (128-bit) XMM registers and 4 stores (from the SSE instruction set.) Or, 2 loads, followed by two stores to/from 256-bit YMM registers. Or even a single load/store using a 512-bit ZMM register. However, while you can be sure every CPU in use today has SSE, your certainty drops a little for AVX, and a lot for AVX2. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) as a starting point.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: If none of the above has any meaning for you, I suggest you forget this approach because it will involve Assembly, compiler intrinsics, non-portability, bugs and heartbreak!

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: By the way, did you try the code in my answer at all? Did it make much of a difference?

Comment: Right, I didn't want to get into assembler, but I agree that this would speed things up. This would unfortunately make the code dependent on the size of the bitsets which was something I wanted to avoid. The method you posted seems to be working, and it is a lot faster now.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: Right then. But you still can try idea #2 from the answer, using an aligned allocator and "*placement `new`*". Also, I strongly suggest you leave the `assert`s intact and even add a few if you can think of any! It would save a lot of headaches if someday the implementation for `bitset` changes or your sizes become non-multiples of 8.